# Init.d startup script not working for No-IP

Tags: bash, init.d

I have just installed No-IP on a brand new Ubuntu 12.04 install. The program starts fine when I start it from the CLI, but if I try to make this startup script work it won't start.

I got this script from their install instructions:

```
#! /bin/sh
# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc
case "$1" in
    start)
    echo "Starting noip2."
    /usr/local/bin/noip2
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Shutting down noip2."
    killall -TERM /usr/local/bin/noip2
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

The CL is correct because if I run `/usr/local/bin/noip2` it starts. But the script itself won't start it.

What do I have wrong in there? The script is executable:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root   299 Jan 12 13:28 noip*
```

**EDIT**

If I try the Init.d script it also works:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/noip start
```

It starts up just fine that way without a hitch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should run this (if you have not done so):

```
sudo update-rc.d noip2 defaults
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy, I created a line in root crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/noip2
```

When i power on or reboot my machine, the daemon starts automatically

Comment: I tried this, and the process is there when it boots, but the IP is not updated, why???

Comment: ok, I guess what was happening is that it was running the command before launching the network interface, so if you do `sleep 30 && /usr/local/bin/noip2` it will work. Therefore I'm upvoting this for being the simplest solution of all, no need to tinker with init.d scripts!

Comment: javier and @knocte thanks! This works great! Very easy and no need to mess with `init.d` scripts. It should be noted that you need to specify the **full path** of `noip2` in the crontab file (`sudo crontab -e`) as simply specifying `sleep 30 && noip2` **won't work**.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the:

```
 sudo update-rc.d noip2 defaults
```

you should also set permissions of:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/noip
```

Then you should be able to start and stop. tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

following these directions from:
[How To Install No-ip2 On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS In Order To Host Servers On A Dynamic IP Address](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-no-ip2-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-in-order-to-host-servers-on-a-dynamic-ip-address)

Comment: Then need to go to chmod 700 per those instructions in the link so only root can run it.

Answer (score 1):

and I had to add the line above but with root as user and now it works fine for me.

```
@reboot    root  /usr/local/bin/noip2
```

to edit crontab

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you symlink to the /etc/init.d script from any /etc/rc?.d directory? I have

```
/etc/rc0.d/K10no-ip.com -> ../init.d/no-ip.com.sh*
/etc/rc1.d/K10no-ip.com -> ../init.d/no-ip.com.sh*
/etc/rc2.d/S90no-ip.com -> ../init.d/no-ip.com.sh*
/etc/rc3.d/S90no-ip.com -> ../init.d/no-ip.com.sh*
/etc/rc4.d/S90no-ip.com -> ../init.d/no-ip.com.sh*
/etc/rc5.d/S90no-ip.com -> ../init.d/no-ip.com.sh*
/etc/rc6.d/K10no-ip.com -> ../init.d/no-ip.com.sh*
```

Comment: That is what `update-rc.d` is for. :)